# Tag Synonym Request - [document-library] -> [doclib]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

I have suggested synonym [doclib] for tag [document-library]

Please review

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/tags/document-library/synonyms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done! Thank you for your effort here Amal! Really appreciated!

Comment: Thanks Benny! Really appreciate it.